# Every maximal ideal of a commutative unitary ring is prime (Proof explanation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

First off, I would not like to use any facts about quotient rings. I've got a proof but I need further explanations for some steps.

> **Theorem** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then any maximal ideal of $R$ is prime.

*Proof*: Let $M$ be maximal ideal of $R$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $M$ is not prime. That is there are some $a,b\in R$ s.t. $ab\in M$ and $a,b\notin M$. Consider the ideal $(a)+M$. We have that $(a)+M$ is strictly larger than $M$ thus $R=(a)+M$ by maximality of $M$. Since $R$ is unitary, we have $1\in R=(a)+M$
so
$$1=ra+m$$
for $r\in R,m\in M$
similarly, we have $R=(b)+M$ and
$$1=sb+n$$
for some $s\in R, n\in M$
From these equalities, we obtain
\begin{align*}
1&=1\cdot1\\
&=(ra+m)(sb+n)\\
&=rsab+ran+msb+mn
\end{align*}
Since $ab,m,n$ are all in $M$ the last expression is in $M$. This yields that $1\in M$ so $M=R$. Since maximal ideal is a proper ideal by definition, this is a contradiction. Thus, R must be prime.

Now, I am quite unsure about some steps, what exactly means the ideal $(a)+M$? Is it a ideal of the form $\{ra+m,r\in R,m\in M\}$? That's what im getting, right? Then, why should the expression $rsab+ran+msb+mn$ be in $M$?
EDIT: Also, why should $1\in M$ imply that $M=R$?

Comment: $(a)+M$ is indeed what you wrote. The expression $rsab+ran+msb+mn\in M$ because $ab,n, m$ do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ab\in M$ implies that $rs(ab)\in M$ since $M$ is an ideal, $n,m\in M$ implies that $(ra)n, (sb)m, mn\in M$ since $M$ is an ideal, we deduce that $rsab+ran+msb+mn=rs(ab)+ran+sbm+nm$ is a sum of elements of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for that, got this now, would you please explain one more step in the proof? (Edited my OP)

Comment: If $1$ is in $M$, just by definition  $M$ is closed under multipilication by elements of $R$, so $R \cdot 1=R$, and hence all of $R$ is in $M$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks for that! I got myself confused about two terms: unitary ring, and ring with unity, where unity means an invertible element, but unitary ring means there is multiplicative identity, and as I just found out, this has nothing to do with the theorem that any ideal with unity is the whole ring. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a proof that relies on some known facts.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $M\subset R$ be maximal. Then by a fact or theorem, this is true if and only if $R/M$ is a field and fields are integral domains (another fact). Thus $R/M$ is an integral domain. And there’s a fact that $R/M$ is an integral domain if and only if $M$ is prime, and we are done.

Two of these three facts require some proof however but they aren’t too bad.  The other fact (fields are I ntegral domains) is a matter of definition.